# Access ruby image asset in javascript code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an img tag that is implemented with an id.

```
<img src="http://www.beached.tv/assets/pause-c1c0a3d060f908372ebecf2eb7e7c018.svg" id="play-button" />
```

In my javascript code I have an onclick event to change the image source of the id "play-button". The image goes from a play icon to a pause icon. This is the line that changes the image in the event:

```
$("#play-button").attr("src", "http://www.beached.tv/assets/pause-c1c0a3d060f908372ebecf2eb7e7c018.svg");
```

I want to do the same thing but instead of referencing a url, i just want to use the image file itself from my rails assets.

The first part can be done with:

```
<%= image_tag("play.svg"), :id => "play-button" %>
```

How can I modify the javascript line to load pause.svg?

Comment: Images can be used in one of two ways: 1) As a URL where the browser will fetch the image from some host.  2) As a data URI where the actual image data is encoded into the URI and the browser decodes it from the URI and uses it directly (e.g. the image data was already included in the page).  The second way is generally more complicated and not supported in older browsers so I'm wondering why you would just expose the image as an image resource so it could be accessed by the browser via URL just like your other image?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the URL's to the image tag as data attributes:

```
<%= image_tag("play.svg", :id => "play-button", :data => { 'play-url' => image_path('play.svg'), 'pause-url' => image_path('pause.svg') } %>
```

Then in your javascript you can access those data attribute and use the urls when switching images:

```
var playButton = $("#play-button"),
    playImgSrc = playButton.data('play-url'),
    pauseImgSrc = playButton.data('pause-url');

// Switch to play button:
playButton.attr("src", playImgSrc);

// Switch to pause button:
playButton.attr("src", pauseImgSrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use erb templating in js too (`your_file.js.erb`) :

```
$("#play-button").attr("src", '<%= image_tag("play.svg") %>');
```